# How to return a pointer to pointer in cython?

Tags: c++, pointers, cython

I am new to cython and I am trying to wrap some C++ code.  For the primitive data types such as int, I can get the values returned from C++.  But, I having trouble returning pointer to pointer object to a 2D array (**double elev_data, **double mask_data) below:

.pyx file:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
import numpy as no
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "params.h":
        cdef cppclass params:
                params()
                int nrows
                int ncols
                double get_yllcorner()
                double get_xllcorner()
                double get_cellsize()
                string get_elev_filename()
                int nodata_value
                double **elev_data
                double **mask_data

def class PyParams:
        cdef params* thisptr # hold a C++ instance
        def __cinit__(self):
                self.thisptr = new params()
        def __dealloc__(self):
                del self.thisptr

        def get_nrows(self):
                return self.thisptr.nrows

        def get_ncols(self):
                return self.thisptr.ncols

        def get_yllcorner(self):
                return self.thisptr.get_yllcorner()

        def get_xllcorner(self):
                return self.thisptr.get_xllcorner()

        def get_cellsize(self):
                return self.thisptr.get_cellsize()

        def get_elev_filename(self):
                return self.thisptr.get_elev_filename()

        def get_nodata_value(self):
                return self.thisptr.nodata_value
```

My question is I can return double **elev_data and double **mask_data.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you stored `elev_data` and `elev_mask` as a 1D array and accessed it as `elev_data[y*nrows+x]` instead of using a pointer to pointer.